# What is the right methodology to assign costs to edges of a network?

Tags: network, cost-path

I am producing a routing facility for cycling safety based on an OSM network. The edges of this network have costs and these are calculated from different criteria both related to intrinsic (as the grade of road) and extrinsic (number of accidents per edge) characteristics. I already have found a method to assign costs but I do not know how to scale and weight them in order to make the routing coherent with my objective. My objective is to avoid dangerous edges assigning them higher costs and prefer safe roads and cycling paths, Dijkstras pg_routing actually does that but dangerous points are avoided "too much" and least cost paths are safe but incredibly long and "wriggly" . I tried to search some papers but I have not found anything related to my case, they are all much related to the criteria definition rather than to their application to a network model.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. One would be to determine your weighted values *before* assigning them to the edges. Another would be to put in a base cost for the edge (simply based on ride time/whatever) and then use network features such as barriers (note the difference between a *restriction* barrier and a *cost* barrier) to add a unit cost based on a weighting scheme that translates your factors into units. Either way, you have to come up with an appropriate weighting scheme and factor classification.

For instance, a segment might only take x minutes to ride and be the ideal route. However it might be a segment that has lots of accidents. Let's say you've taken your range of accidents and classed it - 1-10 is low, 11-20 is risky, and 20+ is avoid. You could then translate those classes into a cost - low adds no time (x+0), risky doubles the time (2x), and avoid adds something overly high like 999 to the time.

The problem here actually *is* the criteria definition, and more specifically weighting and classifying/getting them on a common scale.